# Separate a comma delimited string located in a cell to a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a comma delimited string (`aad,adaa,,dadae,,,eresa,,baaa`) in cell `A1` of `Sheet1` which I want to split and insert values in a column such as:

```
aad
adaa

dadae


eresa

baaa
```

Empty values will skip a cell and insert the string in next cell.

I am able to separate the string to a row but how could I do it to a column?

Here is my line to split the string to a row:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").TextToColumns
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `WorksheetFunction.Transpose()` after splitting to columns.

No need to use `TextToColumns` either, `Split` will suffice:

```
Range("A1:A9").value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Split("aad,adaa,,dadae,,,eresa,,baaa", ","))
```

Comment: Is there a way to start from a particular location withing a string? For e.g. I want to start populating the cells starting from the term after 6th comma. so in above example it will populate "eresa" in cell A1 and so on. Can this be done?

Comment: @user793468 Not in the lazy way. Save result into a variant variable, loop starting from index 6, outputting one element at time.